# (Java Minecraft 1.14) Does a scoreboard tag affect entity despawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can [scoreboard tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags) affect entity despawning? I checked the wiki, but there is no mention of it. Logically, it seems like the answer would be no, because they just classify/identify entities, but name-tagging an entity makes it despawn-proof, so maybe tags do too? Just wanting to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only NBT-tag that affects mob despawning is the `PersistenceRequired`-tag, a custom name does NOT change this behaviour.

This command summons a renamed zombie that will despawn:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"zombie"}'}
```

This command summons a renamed zombie that will not despawn:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"zombie"}',PersistenceRequired:1b}
```

Changing the name of a zombie with a name tag will change both the name and set the `PersistenceRequired`-tag to 1.

If a zombie picks up an item, then the `PersistenceRequired`-tag will be set to 1.
<sup>Credits go to [Fabian Röling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355572/java-minecraft-1-14-does-a-scoreboard-tag-affect-entity-despawning/355578?noredirect=1#comment500920_355578) for mentioning this in the comments</sup>

In conclusion, using this command will not make the nearest zombie despawn-proof:

```
/tag @e[type=minecraft:zombie,sort=nearest,limit=1] add zombie
```

*Note: I only tested wether or not a zombie despawns in those cases, it may be possible that they take longer to despawn, or despawn quicker, or that they are affected in some other way.*

*Note 2: I only tested this with zombies, but it should apply to any entity*

Comment: Maybe you also want to write somewhere in your answer that picking up items and nametagging sets `PersistenceRequired` to `true`.

Comment: @FabianRöling I did mention the nametagging ("Changing the name of an entity with a name tag will change both the name and set the PersistenceRequired-tag to 1.") and I haven't tested about picking up items, I will test that and add it to the answer.

Comment: @FabianRöling Items don't have the `PersistenceRequired`-tag, neither before picking them up, nor after dropping them. Can you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @FabianRöling I figured it out and tested it, I will add it to the answer now

Comment: I'm trying to make a small percentage of bats randomly turn into vampires, so I wanted to make sure that if I tagged a bat to say it had already been decided to *not* turn into a vampire by the RNG that it wouldn't not despawn or something.

Comment: @Nik3141 You can set the `PersistenceRequired`-tag to 1 to make sure they won't despawn, I'm assuming that you know how to do that, so I leave it at that.